# How to make an app like true caller with react native?

Tags: react-native

I would like to create an app like true-caller using react native
I tried to use detection libraries but they didn't work in background mode especially for iOS.
Is there any workaround to do this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -2):

Try This one
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-truecaller

its works for both android and ios

Comment: This package is deprecated & not working.